# Unable to write to a file and then scan that line after... why?

Tags: c, file-io

Here I am writing "1000" to "file.txt" and then trying to scan that number from the file and save it into an integer variable then print it out. When running the code I keep getting "number: 0". The number writes to the file successfully whether file.txt existed or not but scanning never works.

```
int main(){
    //declare file handle
    FILE *filePtr;
    int num = 0;
    
    //point handle to correct file
    filePtr = fopen("file.txt", "w+");
    fprintf(filePtr,"1000\n");
    fscanf(filePtr, "%d", &num);
    printf("Number: %d\n", num);    
}
```

I tried printing the memory address of the file handle before and after writing to the file hoping it would maybe be pointing to the next line (which would be blank) and then scan that line. Since it is empty the num variable would keep its value of 0 because it did not scan the line before it which contained 1000. However, the mem address stayed the same.

Comment: You may need to flush and rewind the file to get data back out.

Comment: `FILE` is a structure that contains all sorts of information about an open file. The information in the structure is used by the standard library functions when accessing the file. So `filePtr` is just a pointer to the structure. That's why the address stayed the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a write, *flush* and *rewind* to read from the beginning. [@tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75391493/unable-to-write-to-a-file-and-then-scan-that-line-after-why/75391606#comment133027445_75391493)

```
fprintf(filePtr,"1000\n");
fflush(filePtr);
rewind(filePtr);
fscanf(filePtr, "%d", &num);
```

---

> When a file is opened with update mode (’+’ as the second or third character in the above list of mode argument values), both input and output may be performed on the associated stream. However, **output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call** to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`, `fsetpos`, or `rewind`), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file...
> C17dr § 7.21.5.3 7

---

OP's investigation  "tried printing the memory address of the file handle" if certainty implementation specific, but is certainly just reporting some data structure address.  [@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75391493/unable-to-write-to-a-file-and-then-scan-that-line-after-why/75391606#comment133027699_75391493)

Comment: Awesome, I got a lot of good insight from everyones comments. Understanding that the ptr just points to the structure and does not actually move through memory is really important. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @ACE_26 What `FILE *` points to is a _black box_.  Best to assume little about it.